# Anyconnect example configuration

Tags: cisco-anyconnect

I need to implement two types of Anyconnect. One has to be IPSec based, AAA authentication for users and certificate based authentication in tunnel (IKEv2). Second has to be SSL (tunnel mode), certificate based user authentication (user and machine certificate), and also certificate based authentication in tunnel (IKEv2). Certificates can be self-signed. Can anyone paste me cli configuration or point to some manual for my requirements?

Comment: It's the VPN head end (concentrator) device that you will be configuring, therefore we would need to know what make and model that device is.

Comment: Headend is ASA 5508-X, Software Version 9.6(1)

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so, you should accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Main configuration is ok, but additional questions are not answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below configuration for both cases from *[AnyConnect over IKEv2 to ASA with AAA and Certificate Authentication](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/113692-technote-anyconnect-00.html)*:

> ## Configuration on the ASA
>
> This section describes the ASA configurations that are required before
>   the connection occurs.
>
> **Note:** The Cisco Adaptive Security Device Manager (ASDM) allows you to create the basic configuration with only a few clicks. Cisco
>   recommends that you use it in order to avoid mistakes.
>
> ### Crypto Map Configuration
>
> Here is a crypto map example configuration:
>
> ```
> crypto dynamic-map DYN 1 set pfs group1
> crypto dynamic-map DYN 1 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal secure
> crypto dynamic-map DYN 1 set reverse-route
> crypto map STATIC 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic DYN
> crypto map STATIC interface outside
> ```
>
> ### IPsec Proposals
>
> Here is an IPsec proposal example configuration:
>
> ```
> crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal secure
>  protocol esp encryption aes 3des
>  protocol esp integrity sha-1
> crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256-SHA
>  protocol esp encryption aes-256
>  protocol esp integrity sha-1
> ```
>
> ### IKEv2 Policies
>
> Here is an IKEv2 policy example configuration:
>
> ```
> crypto ikev2 policy 1
>  encryption aes-256
>  integrity sha
>  group 5 2
>  prf sha
>  lifetime seconds 86400
> crypto ikev2 policy 10
>  encryption aes-192
>  integrity sha
>  group 5 2
>  prf sha
>  lifetime seconds 86400
> crypto ikev2 policy 20
>  encryption aes
>  integrity sha
>  group 5 2
>  prf sha
>  lifetime seconds 86400
> crypto ikev2 policy 30
>  encryption 3des
>  integrity sha
>  group 5 2
>  prf sha
>  lifetime seconds 86400
> crypto ikev2 policy 40
>  encryption des
>  integrity sha
>  group 5 2
>  prf sha
>  lifetime seconds 86400
> ```
>
> ### Client Services and Certificate
>
> You must enable client services and certificates on the correct
>   interface, which is the outside interface in this case. Here is an
>   example configuration:
>
> ```
> crypto ikev2 enable outside client-services port 443
> crypto ikev2 remote-access trustpoint OUTSIDE
> ssl trust-point OUTSIDE outside
> ```
>
> **Note:** The same trustpoint is also assigned for Secure Sockets Layer (SSL), which is intended and required.
>
> ### Enable AnyConnect Profile
>
> You must enable the AnyConnect profile on the ASA. Here is an example
>   configuration:
>
> ```
> webvpn
>  enable outside
>  anyconnect image disk0:/anyconnect-win-3.0.5080-k9.pkg 1 regex "Windows NT"
>  anyconnect profiles Anyconnect disk0:/anyconnect.xml
>  anyconnect enable
>  tunnel-group-list enable
> ```
>
> ### Username, Group-Policy, and Tunnel-Group
>
> Here is an example configuration for a basic username, group-policy,
>   and tunnel-group on the ASA:
>
> ```
> group-policy GroupPolicy_AC internal
> group-policy GroupPolicy_AC attributes
>  dns-server value 4.2.2.2
>  vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2 l2tp-ipsec ssl-client ssl-clientless
>  default-domain value cisco.com
>  webvpn
>   anyconnect profiles value Anyconnect type user
> username cisco password 3USUcOPFUiMCO4Jk encrypted privilege 15
> tunnel-group AC type remote-access
> tunnel-group AC general-attributes
>  address-pool VPN-POOL
>  default-group-policy GroupPolicy_AC
> tunnel-group AC webvpn-attributes
>  authentication aaa certificate
>  group-alias AC enable
>  group-url https://bsns-asa5520-1.cisco.com/AC enable
>  without-csd
> ```
>
> ### AnyConnect Profile
>
> Here is an example profile with the relevant parts shown in bold:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <AnyConnectProfile xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/encoding/"
>  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=
>  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/encoding/ AnyConnectProfile.xsd">
>    <ClientInitialization>
>     <UseStartBeforeLogon UserControllable="true">false</UseStartBeforeLogon>
>     <AutomaticCertSelection UserControllable="true">false
>       </AutomaticCertSelection>
>     <ShowPreConnectMessage>false</ShowPreConnectMessage>
>     <CertificateStore>All</CertificateStore>
>     <CertificateStoreOverride>false</CertificateStoreOverride>
>     <ProxySettings>Native</ProxySettings>
>     <AllowLocalProxyConnections>true</AllowLocalProxyConnections>
>     <AuthenticationTimeout>12</AuthenticationTimeout>
>     <AutoConnectOnStart UserControllable="true">false</AutoConnectOnStart>
>     <MinimizeOnConnect UserControllable="true">true</MinimizeOnConnect>
>     <LocalLanAccess UserControllable="true">false</LocalLanAccess>
>     <ClearSmartcardPin UserControllable="true">true</ClearSmartcardPin>
>     <AutoReconnect UserControllable="false">true
>        <AutoReconnectBehavior UserControllable="false">DisconnectOnSuspend 
>         </AutoReconnectBehavior>
>     </AutoReconnect>
>     <AutoUpdate UserControllable="false">true</AutoUpdate>
>     <RSASecurIDIntegration UserControllable="true">Automatic
>       </RSASecurIDIntegration>
>     <WindowsLogonEnforcement>SingleLocalLogon</WindowsLogonEnforcement>
>     <WindowsVPNEstablishment>LocalUsersOnly</WindowsVPNEstablishment>
>     <AutomaticVPNPolicy>false</AutomaticVPNPolicy>
>     <PPPExclusion UserControllable="false">Disable
>        <PPPExclusionServerIP UserControllable="false"></PPPExclusionServerIP>
>     </PPPExclusion>
>     <EnableScripting UserControllable="false">false</EnableScripting>
>     <EnableAutomaticServerSelection UserControllable="false">false
>        <AutoServerSelectionImprovement>20</AutoServerSelectionImprovement>
>        <AutoServerSelectionSuspendTime>4</AutoServerSelectionSuspendTime>
>     </EnableAutomaticServerSelection>
>     <RetainVpnOnLogoff>false
>     </RetainVpnOnLogoff>
>   </ClientInitialization>
>   <ServerList>
>       <HostEntry>
>           <HostName>bsns-asa5520-1</HostName>
>           <HostAddress>bsns-asa5520-1.cisco.com</HostAddress>
>           <UserGroup>AC</UserGroup>
>       <PrimaryProtocol>IPsec</PrimaryProtocol>
>       </HostEntry>
>   </ServerList>
> </AnyConnectProfile>
> ```
>
> Here are some important notes about this configuration example:
>
> - When you create the profile, the HostAddress must match the    Certificate Name (CN) on the certificate that is used for IKEv2.
>     Enter the **crypto ikev2 remote-access trustpoint** command in order
>     to    define this.
> - The UserGroup must match the name of the tunnelgroup to which the    IKEv2 connection falls. If they do not match, the connection often
>     fails and the debugs indicate a Diffie-Hellman (DH) group mismatch or 
>     a similar false negative.
>
> ### Verification on ASA
>
> Enter this command on the ASA in order to verify that the connection
>   uses IKEv2 as well as AAA and certificate authentication:
>
> ```
> bsns-asa5520-1# show vpn-sessiondb detail anyconnect filter name cisco
>
> Session Type: AnyConnect Detailed
> Username : cisco Index : 6
> Assigned IP : 172.16.99.5 Public IP : 1.2.3.4
> Protocol : IKEv2 IPsecOverNatT AnyConnect-Parent
> License : AnyConnect Premium
> Encryption : AES256 AES128 Hashing : none SHA1 SHA1
> Bytes Tx : 0 Bytes Rx : 960
> Pkts Tx : 0 Pkts Rx : 10
> Pkts Tx Drop : 0 Pkts Rx Drop : 0
> Group Policy : GroupPolicy_AC Tunnel Group : AC
> Login Time : 15:45:41 UTC Tue Aug 28 2012
> Duration : 0h:02m:41s
> Inactivity : 0h:00m:00s
> NAC Result : Unknown
> VLAN Mapping : N/A VLAN : none
> IKEv2 Tunnels: 1
> IPsecOverNatT Tunnels: 1
> AnyConnect-Parent Tunnels: 1
> AnyConnect-Parent:
>  Tunnel ID : 6.1
>  Public IP : 1.2.3.4
>  Encryption : none Auth Mode : Certificate and userPassword
>  Idle Time Out: 30 Minutes Idle TO Left : 27 Minutes
>  Client Type : AnyConnect
>  Client Ver : 3.0.08057
> IKEv2:
>  Tunnel ID : 6.2
>  UDP Src Port : 60468 UDP Dst Port : 4500
> Rem Auth Mode: Certificate and userPassword
>  Loc Auth Mode: rsaCertificate
>  Encryption : AES256 Hashing : SHA1
>  Rekey Int (T): 86400 Seconds Rekey Left(T): 86238 Seconds
>  PRF : SHA1 D/H Group : 5
>  Filter Name :
>  Client OS : Windows
> IPsecOverNatT:
>  Tunnel ID : 6.3
>  Local Addr : 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0/0/0
>  Remote Addr : 172.16.99.5/255.255.255.255/0/0
>  Encryption : AES128 Hashing : SHA1\
>  Encapsulation: Tunnel
>  Rekey Int (T): 28800 Seconds Rekey Left(T): 28638 Seconds
>  Rekey Int (D): 4608000 K-Bytes Rekey Left(D): 4608000 K-Bytes
>  Idle Time Out: 30 Minutes Idle TO Left : 27 Minutes
>  Bytes Tx : 0 Bytes Rx : 960
>  Pkts Tx : 0 Pkts Rx : 10
> ```

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here, since the answer isn't usable once the link or its content changes. Please consider adding more details to your answer./

Comment: Ok , this configuration looks complete. I just have few more questions. 1. Can certificate for IKEv2 and SSL be self-signed? (because the limitations from this link http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-firewalls/200602-Configure-ASA-as-a-Local-CA-Server-and-A.html ) 2. When configuring server list..."user group" "must match the name of the tunnel group"..is that the name of Connection profile? 3. While configuring group policy, we have command "anyconnect profiles value Anyconnect type user" ... what does this type stands for "user"..somewhere I see "vpn" there?

Comment: 4. When configuring Tunnel group, for IPSec we have command: "group-url https://bsns-asa5520-1.cisco.com/AC enable" ...Does the user enters this URL (https://bsns-asa5520-1.cisco.com/AC) in browser when he want to connect for the first time and download AnyConnect, as to start web-launch? 5. Does user have to have priviledge 15?

Comment: Anyone has answers to my questions?